# Programmatically setting some Interface Builder Options

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

For roughly a hundred reasons, I simply had to make this UIViewController subclass view programmatically. Just one, every other view uses IB to make its layouts.

Well now i got landed with the task to make the app auto-rotate. Which is fine for the most part, but I need help understanding some of these layout options... specific to Autosizing and Alignment

How do I set this here (this would be object known as "header", so `[header setAutoresizingMask:...]`

[image]

And as well as this one

[image]

And that ones as `_mapView`

Ive kind of been continuously hammering away at the available options but either its not making any discernible difference, or im not setting the right options...

```
    header = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [header setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 170)];

    // this one shoves the header button when in landscape mode to out of view :\
    [header setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    // the header remains left aligned when in landscape mode...
    [header setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];


    [header setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [header setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [header addTarget:self action:@selector(goHome) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    _mapView = [[[SPMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
    [_mapView setDelegate:self];




    [self.view addSubview:_mapView];
    [self.view addSubview:header];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first one :

```
CGRect newFrame = mainView.frame;
        newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(160, 170);
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(768, 170);
        myView.frame = newFrame;
        myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

and for the second one :

```
CGRect newFrame = mainView.frame;
            newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(160, 416);
            newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 247);
            myView.frame = newFrame;
            myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: No prob mate ;) If there will be any problem, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Yup that worked, had to tweak the origin and sizes, but otherwise looking good to me, thanks!